# OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 219-03-28 09:36:32 While converting str to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two formats of dates in a csv

```
2019-08-11 07:43:28.977 (date1)
```

and

```
2019-08-11 06:30:00 (date2)
```

I used the following command to convert the first one and it converted successfully

```
contests['date1'] =  pd.to_datetime(contests['date1'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But when I try the same command for date 2 it throws me the error
`OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp` but there are no milliseconds nor have I specified them in the format. What should the correct `format` be for me to parse this date format ?

**EDIT**
`date1` and `date2` are separate columns.
for this particular date in date2 column the format does not work `219-03-28 09:36:32`

Comment: How working if use only `contests['date1'] =  pd.to_datetime(contests['date1'])` ?

Comment: For me working well `parse_dates=['date1']` parameter to `pd.read_csv`

Comment: I am able to convert `date1`. `date2` is the issue

Comment: hmmm, is possible share datetime which raise error?

Comment: `2019-08-11 07:43:28.977`. please declare this as a string and try to convert it to datetime using `pandas.to_datetime` function

Comment: Not understand, cannot omit `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` ?

Comment: This date gives error `219-03-28 09:36:32` for this format `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

Comment: I understand, but if there is 2 formats of datetimes, why not remove `format` parameetr? in another words, is necessary?

Comment: Please see the edit. Added details that `date1` and `date2` are separate columns. For the whole date1 column this format works. Even if I remove `format` parameter it fails in date2 column

Comment: so in date2 are dates `2019-08-11 07:43:28.977` and `2019-08-11 06:30:00` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert using `to_datetime(df['B'])` without giving a specific format and it will recognize the format.

If you want to define the format then you can specify this `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'` in your code.